# Dealing with multiple toggles

Tags: jquery, toggle

I'm stuck in a toggle() nightmare, and am finally asking for help.

What I want is pretty simple, I have three links:

```
a.showcountries.bronze
a.showcountries.silver
a.showcountries.gold
```

and three boxes:

```
.countries.bronze
.countries.silver
.countries.gold
```

You can probably aready see what I'm trying to do. All boxes are hidden buy default, when I click bronze it slides bronze down, click it again it slides up, and so on. The problem I'm having is that all three boxes occupy the same space on the page, so I can only have one box open at any one time. So I click bronze, down slides the bronze box, and if I then click silver it should slide back up and the silver one slides down...

```
$('a.showcountries.bronze').toggle(
        function(){
            $('.countries.silver, .countries.gold').slideUp();
            $('.countries.bronze').slideDown();
        },
        function(){
            $('.countries.bronze').slideUp();
        }
    );
    $('a.showcountries.silver').toggle(
        function(){
            $('.countries.bronze, .countries.gold').slideUp();
            $('.countries.silver').slideDown();
        },
        function(){
            $('.countries.silver').slideUp();
        }
    );
    $('a.showcountries.gold').toggle(
        function(){
            $('.countries.silver, .countries.bronze').slideUp();
            $('.countries.gold').slideDown();
        },
        function(){
            $('.countries.gold').slideUp();
        }
    );
```

I'm struggling to get the transitions to work, as the toggles appear to go out of sync and sometimes I end up having to click a link twice before it does anything. I'm also sure theres a solution that uses a LOT less code. I did try detecting the class and pass it to  a common function to do all this, but couldn't get it to play.

Comment: You should change your elements class for example .showcountries.gold to .showcountries_gold or something like that just remove middle dots of your class name.

Comment: @kst: the dots are not part of the class name; they delimit separate classes. In CSS's selector syntax, `div.class-a.class-b` selects a `div` with both `class-a` and `class-b`.

Comment: Thank god people traditionally only give out three types of medals, what are you going to do if there was five? :P

Comment: It sure can come in handy with jQuery, but I'm also not to fond of using multiple class selectors...

Comment: @Will Vousden Ohh! miss understanding. thanks for your way. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a jsFiddle that should get you close.

[Check it here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/jHvjD/5/)

It's based on a click event, and you use the id to check which div you want to show, and close that one if it is already open. Can you get your html/css/js setup this way?

Answer (score 4):

`toggle()` as an event remembers the previous click and runs the alternate function on the next one.  You're better off using a single click event and checking visibility.  Something like this might work better for you:

```
$(".showcountries").click(function () {
    var cls = this.className.match(/gold|silver|bronze/),
        box = $(".countries."+cls[0]);

    // slideUp() on all .countries elements
    $(".countries").not(box).slideUp();

    box.slideToggle();
});
```

**Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kSrvZ/1** (thanks to YiJiang for suggesting [*slideToggle()*](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) on chat).

Comment: +1 Nice. The `$(box)` wrap is unnecessary, though, as you're already holding a jQuery collection. I would use `box.is(':visible') ? box.slideUp() : box.slideDown();` instead (shorthand for comment clarity).

Comment: Hmmm, seems you edited it to an even better solution in the meantime :)

Comment: @jensgram: yeah thanks, I haven't had my coffee this morning ;-)

Comment: I like the fact that the more abstract someone can think (thus a better coder), the less if-statements he needs! +1 for this solution!

Comment: @Justus: haha yeah, that's so true. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Unless I've got the wrong end of the stick, I don't think [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) does what you think it does. You should be using the `click` event for this,</strike> and I'd also use an ID rather than a class for your links. Something like this should work (untested):

```
$('a.showcountries').click(function()
{
    var class = $(this).attr('id');
    $('.countries').not('.' + class).slideUp();
    $('.countries').filter('.' + class).slideDown();
});
```

Edit: I stand corrected! You learn something every day :)