# jquery toggle tabs with an extra toggle function

Tags: jquery, tabs

I've got some tabs setup; here's what they currently do:

1. hide content when page is opened
2. show content on tab click (with a toggle so user can show/hide/show/hide the content)
3. active tab changes color when selected

The issue: when the user clicks on one of the tabs and shows the content, and then clicks on the other tab, both sets of content show (like a cumulative toggle).

I want to set it up so that if the user clicks a tab and shows the content, and then clicks the other tab, the content showing for the first tab clicked will hide.

Here's another SO question that deals with something similar, but it doesn't include the active class code I have - [Dealing with multiple toggles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203026/dealing-with-multiple-toggles) and the JS that works - http://jsfiddle.net/jHvjD/5/

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.tab_contents').hide();

  $('.tab').click(function() {

      $(this.rel).toggle();

  $('#tabs_container > .tabs > li.active')
      .removeClass('active');

  $(this).parent().addClass('active');

  $('#tabs_container > .tab_contents_container > div.tab_contents_active')
      .removeClass('tab_contents_active');

  $(this.rel).addClass('tab_contents_active');
 });
});
```

**HTML**

```
     <div id="tabs_container">

      <!-- These are the tabs -->
      <ul class="tabs">
        <li>
          <a href="#" rel="#tab_1_contents" class="tab">Option 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" rel="#tab_2_contents" class="tab">Option 2</a></li>
      </ul>

      <div class="clear"></div>

      <div class="tab_contents_container">

        <!-- Tab 1 Contents -->
        <div id="tab_1_contents" class="tab_contents tab_contents_active">Option 1 stuff        </div>

        <!-- Tab 2 Contents -->
        <div id="tab_2_contents" class="tab_contents">Option 2 stuff</div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to use `active` to make an element visible or actually toggling the display?

Comment: what about using [jquery UI Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/)?

Comment: @JaredPar - The active class highlights the tab in use and when clicked, actually toggles the content.

Comment: @JMax - that doesn't solve the issue; I'm already using jquery; I need to know how to shift a toggle to apply to multiple selectors

Comment: @JMax - meaning I don't think the UI library gives me any easier solution

Comment: @chowwy: what I was saying is that there are already packaged and easy to use solutions to create tabs (especially while you are already using the jquery framework)

Comment: Try this one http://jsfiddle.net/f49H7/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('.tab_contents').hide();

  $('.tab').click(function(){
    var target = $(this.rel);          
    $('.tab_contents').not(target).hide();
    target.toggle();

  $('#tabs_container > .tabs > li.active')
      .removeClass('active');

  $(this).parent().addClass('active');

  $('#tabs_container > .tab_contents_container > div.tab_contents_active')
      .removeClass('tab_contents_active');

  $(this.rel).addClass('tab_contents_active');
 });
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/GkGyt/2/

Comment: Okay, this works, but is it possible to continue to be able to toggle the items also? Right now the content showing toggles, but I can no longer toggle the tabs--meaning that if the Option 2 content is showing and I click the Option 2 Tab, the content won't hide.

Comment: yeah you can do it easily.. updated the answer and fiddle too. check it out.

Comment: Thank you. This is perfect! I accepted and upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why be so complex -- try the simple first:

```
 $('.tab_contents_active')
    .removeClass('tab_contents_active');
```

instead of

```
$('#tabs_container > .tab_contents_container > div.tab_contents_active')
    .removeClass('tab_contents_active');
```

If that works (which it will) then you can optimize.

I suspect that there is no optimization to the first code, unless your page is very very complex the additional selecters will just make it slower... but it really depends on your dom... try the simple "remove em all" solution first.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this which is much more simpler.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.tab_contents').hide();

  $('.tab').click(function() {
      var activeTabContent = $(this).attr('rel');

      $('#tab_contents').not(activeTabContent).hide()
      .removeClass('tab_contents_active');

      $(activeTabContent).toggle().addClass('tab_contents_active');

      $(this).parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

do `$('.tab_contents_active').toggle();` before removing the class.
this way they will slide up before the new tab slides down.