# On SlideToggle - add CSS class + collapse behavior

Tags: jquery, css

I'm working with [a solution found on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8714300/jquery-toggle-tabs-with-an-extra-toggle-function) for Jquery based slideToggle

In the above code, I'm trying to add 2 new behaviors

1) Change the css class of the toggle buttons (toggle_on, toggle_off)
2) Click inside the sliding container to collapse accordion
3) Click outside (anywhere else on page) to collapse accordion
4) Any other tips to clean up JS code?

Working Code here:
http://jsfiddle.net/jHvjD/118/

HTML

```
<br><br><br><button href="#" id="bronze" class="tab bronzelink">Bronze</button>
<button href="#" id="silver" class="tab silverlink">Silver</button>
<button href="#" id="gold" class="tab goldlink">Gold</button>
<br><br>
<div class="popup bronze">Bronze?</div>
<div class="popup silver">Silver?</div>
<div class="popup gold">Gold?</div>
```

JS (with jquery)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".tab").click(function(){ 
        var medal = $(this).attr("id");
        if($("." + medal + ":visible").length){;
          $("." + medal).slideUp("fast");

        } else {
          $(".popup").slideUp("fast");
          $("." + medal).slideDown("fast");  
        }
    });
});
```

CSS

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    display: none;
}
div.bronze {
    background-color: #aa5555;
    height: 100px;    
}
div.silver {
    background-color: #ccccdd;
    height: 200px;    
}
div.gold {
    background-color: #ddcc00;
    height: 50px;    
}

.toggle_on{
    background:red;
}

.toggle_off{
    background:blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 1st and 4th I will say:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".tab").click(function () {
    $(this).addClass("toggle_on").removeClass("toggle_off").siblings("a.tab").removeClass("toggle_on").addClass("toggle_off");
    var medal = $(this).attr("id");
    if($("." + medal + ":visible").length){
      $("." + medal).slideUp("fast");
      return;
    }
    $(".popup").not("." + medal).slideUp(function () {
        $("." + medal).slideDown();
    });
    });
});
```

and by default add appropriate classes to the tabs i.e. toggle_on, toggle_off.

For 2nd and 3rd:

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
    var container = $(".tab");

    if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
    &&
    container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
    {
        $(".tab").removeClass("toggle_on").addClass("toggle_off");
        $(".popup").slideUp("fast");
    }
});
```

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jHvjD/130/)

Comment: Thanks it works. Added the classes. But upon clicking the toggle button again, the container doesn't seem to be collapsing http://jsfiddle.net/jHvjD/127/

Comment: thanks again. I see what you did. It seems the on/off class doesn't toggle if the toggle link is clicked. In that the toggle works but the red doesn't change back to blue if you click on the link to toggle. Any tips?

Comment: Super worked perfectly! anything in the JS you think needs cleaning up?

Comment: Umm nothing. Its kinda very efficient maintaining the modularity and readability. If it helps considering voting up and marking it as a correct answer.